# Implement conversion of enum types as static "method"

Tags: c#, casting

I'm working with an enumeration and xml files.

Because xml always returns string-values, I need to convert these values to my enum-values.

```
//while reading the xml file:
ItemType = xml.Element("ItemType") != null ?(ProjectTreeItemTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProjectTreeItemTypes), elem.Element("ItemType").Value,true) : ProjectTreeItemTypes.None
```

I'd like to implement something like the always avaialbel .toString() to my enumeration. Is there a way to solve this?

The result should look like this:

```
    ItemType = xml.Element("ItemType") != null ? elem.Element("ItemType").Value.toItemType() : ProjectTreeItemTypes.None
```

Is this possible somehow or similar?
Evene something like simple cast would be nice:

```
ItemType = xml.Element("ItemType") != null ? (ProjectTreeItemTypes)elem.Element("ItemType").Value : ProjectTreeItemTypes.None
```

Thanks

Comment: An extension-method maybe? But that will put the method on **every** string. However not every string actually represents an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write an extension method for that

```cs
public static class Ext
{
    public static ProjectTreeItemTypes ToItemType(this string value)
    {
        return value == null
            ? ProjectTreeItemTypes.None
            : (ProjectTreeItemTypes) Enum.Parse(typeof(ProjectTreeItemTypes), value, true);
    }
}
```

It'll accept `string`, which is [`XElement.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.value?view=netcore-3.1) and return `ProjectTreeItemTypes` enum

The usage example

```cs
ItemType = xml.Element("ItemType")?.Value.ToItemType() ?? ProjectTreeItemTypes.None;
```

Since you can pass a `null` value to extension method, your `null` check can be simplified using [null-conditional operator `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Comment: Thank you, looks very nice. And thanks for the null-conditional operator tip.

Comment: Oh one question, if I use the `?.` operator, I will get null, if xml.Element is null right? So in this case, I will not use it to return ProjectTreeItemTypes.None right?

Comment: @Telefisch yes, you will get `Nullable<ProjectTreeItemTypes>` result, You may add `??` operator at the end, like `xml.Element("ItemType")?.Value.ToItemType() ?? ProjectTreeItemTypes.None`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method in a static class.

```
public static class Extentsion 
{
    public static ProjectTreeItemTypes ToEnum(this XElement elem)
    {
        return elem.Element("ItemType") != null ? 
            (ProjectTreeItemTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProjectTreeItemTypes), elem.Element("ItemType").Value,true) : ProjectTreeItemTypes.None
    }
}
```

And then you will be able to use it like this:

```
xml.ToEnum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension for `XmlElement` that is a wrapper around `Enum.Parse`:

```
static TEnum ParseEnum <TEnum>(this XmlElement element) where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    return Enum.Parse<TEnum>(element.Value);
}
```

Then use like:

```
ItemType = xml.Element("ItemType")?.ParseEnum<ProjectTreeItemTypes>() ?? ProjectTreeItemTypes.None;
```

Or you could make the extension responsible for returning the default:

```
static TEnum TryParseEnum <TEnum>(this XmlElement element, TEnum defaultValue) where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    if (Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(element.Value, out var val))
    {
        return val;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Usage:

```
ItemType = xml.Element("ItemType").TryParseEnum(ProjectTreeItemTypes.None);
```